# Change div width every 1 second by 5px

Tags: javascript

I tried to change div width every 1 second by 5px using JavaScript. How can I make this work?

Here's my code:

```html
   <html>
        <head>
             <title>JS Functions</title>
        </head>
        <body>
         <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:gray" id="box" onclick="bigger()"></div>
            <script>
    
    function bigger()
    {
        var w = 100
        var h = 100
        while(w < 1000, h < 1000)
        {
            w = w+5;
            h = h+5;
            document.getElementById('box').style.width = w
            document.getElementById('box').style.height = h
            setInterval();
        }
    }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can clarify your question? You want it to change every 1 second by 5px in each direction?

Comment: Yes I want it to change every 1 second by 5px in each direction

Comment: Hint: You're changing it by `5` while you say you want to change it by `5px`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No while loop needed. You can just use setInterval:

```js
var w = 100;
var h = 100;
var foo = setInterval(function () {
    if(w>1000) cancelInterval(foo)
    w = w + 5;
    h = h + 5;
    document.getElementById('box').style.width = w + 'px';
    document.getElementById('box').style.height = h + 'px';
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:gray" id="box" onclick="bigger()"></div>
```

Comment: That's by far the best answer. The only thing is, I'm not too sure what will happen if you keep clicking on the `div`?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Well, to be honest I find it more likely that OP was looking for CSS transitions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use setInterval to call your code every second, so move it outside of the `bigger()` function. Also you need the full value for style, including the unit you're using.

try this

```html
<html>
        <head>
             <title>JS Functions</title>
        </head>
        <body>
         <div style="width:100px; height:100px; background:gray" id="box"></div>
            <script>
    
        var w = 100;
        var h = 100;
    function bigger()
    {
        if (w < 1000 && h < 1000) 
        {
            w = w+5;
            h = h+5;
            document.getElementById('box').style.width = w + 'px';
            document.getElementById('box').style.height = h + 'px';
            
        } else {
           clearInterval(int);
       }
    }
              var int = setInterval(bigger, 1000);
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Good call, modified. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome - Apart from that I think there are minor corrections such as closing unclosed declarations and '&&' instead of ',' in the loop/if condition

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a div wth `id='boxToEnlarge'`

**The JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/7qtb1u8e/1/

**And this is the actual code:**

```
function enlargeBox(){

 //get current size
 var currentWidth = document.getElementById('boxToEnlarge').offsetWidth;
 var currentHeight = document.getElementById('boxToEnlarge').offsetHeight;

 //add 5 more pixels to current size
 document.getElementById('boxToEnlarge').style.width = currentWidth + 5 +'px';
 document.getElementById('boxToEnlarge').style.height = currentHeight + 5 +'px';

}

//call the enlargeBox func every 1 sec (1000 milliseconds) 
setInterval(function(){enlargeBox()},1000);
```

---

We are reading the current size of the `div` we want to enlarge then we add 5px to that amount and apply it on it's width/height CSS properties.

We wrap the above in a function and using `setInterval`, we call that function once every n milliseconds, in this case 1000ms which equals 1 second